# How can I find the "main code" for an APK?

Tags: android, apk, reverse-engineering

I was trying to decompile and reverse engineer a APK, just for testing my reverse engineering skills, I did decompile the APK and got both Sources and Resources Folder, the Resources has all the Classes.dex, using the dex2jar I decompiled it but all the code inside it was just Ads and Offer wall stuff, nothing relating to the game it self, there was also a res folder with all the games .dat files and also sounds however they are encrypted. How would I go about to find the APK main code?
Also my knowledge on codding is not the best, but I do have some experience with java.

Tried looking for the encryption method used for the dat and mp3 files and also decompiling DEX classes.

Comment: You should better switch to a decompiler that allows to look at code and resources like Jadx-Gui. Check AndroidManifest.xml for the main activity and got the by clicking on it's class name. Note that games often make use of native .so files which are pretty hard to decompile and understand.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I am modding android applications in mobile. Seems like you are doing the same thing but in PC. Everytime I have to find the code, I used another tool which is named "Current Activity" on mobile and also I using a "MT Manager" (best tool for mobile reverse-engineer).

1st step I do is I turn on the current activity then I will open the target app then it will show the **activity** of the target app where the screen is in display with current activity.

Then I open the MT Manager and open the target app with all dex option. I follow the activity of the target app using the dex folder until I find the correct **class name** after that you will see the assembly language of android application which is **smali** and you have to learn smali language or you can use the feature of mt manager where you can convert smali into java but it requires vip so i suggest you to use another tool for that. Lastly, dig there in the class where you can find a lot of methods in smali language.